# Limit problems in two variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

How would one find the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which $$\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}} {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \to 0$$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ ?

I understand the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit but putting into practice is a bit tricky.

So setting $x=0$ I can see the limit would tend to $0$ for all $\beta > 1$ and vice versa for $\alpha>1$

Assuming a limit of $0$, I then need to look at $| {\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}} {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}-0|$ and from there deduce the circle $\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}<\delta$.

I'm not quite sure about this last step. Is there some way of writing my function in a nice form and then bound it from above?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to express your function in polar coordinates and take it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach to the point $(0,0)$ along the path $y=mx$. Then limit becomes , $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{m^{\alpha}x^{\alpha+\beta}}{x\sqrt{1+m^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{m^{\alpha}x^{\alpha+\beta-1}}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}=0 \text { if } \alpha+\beta-1>0 $$

---

**Update:**

For any arbitrary direction, put $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ in $f(x,y)$. Then $$|f(r,\theta)|=\left|\frac{r^{\alpha+\beta}\cos^{\alpha}\theta\sin^{\beta}\theta}{r}\right|\le r^{\alpha+\beta-1}\to  0 \text{ as } r\to 0$$when $\alpha+\beta>1$.

Comment: This only approaches along 1 line. Do we not need to consider all possible directions? @S.Panja-1729

Comment: Then put $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ in $f(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha + \beta>1$ will do.